# Python libsass sass.complie() not compiling sass

Tags: python, css, flask, sass, libsass

I am having a problem getting libsass to compile SASS files. I can get it to compile SCSS files just fine.

I have a Flask application and I've installed [libsass](http://hongminhee.org/libsass-python/index.html) and I am using the libsass binding [sass](http://hongminhee.org/libsass-python/sass.html). It works well but is missing some functionality - it can't compile SASS but it can compile SCSS. Here's what I did:

In my applicaiton.py file I have

```
from flask import Flask
import sass

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sass.compile(dirname=('client/sass', 'client/css'), source_comments=True)
    app.run()
```

My two test files are `test_scss.scss`, which works:

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

And `test_sass.sass`:

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif
$primary-color: #333

body
  font: 100% $font-stack
  color: $primary-color
```

The documentation says `sass.complie` can take in SASS code but I can only get it to take SCSS code. That is, when I run my application, only the `.scss` file gets compile to CSS. The directory structure of my applicaiton after `sass.compile` runs is:

- client

  - css

    - app.css
    - test_scss.css
  - lib
  - sass

    - test_sass.sass
    - test_scss.scss
- server

  - templates
  - application.py

Someone suggested that I just rename the SASS file to something with a `.scss` extension. Like `test_sass.scss`:'

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif
$primary-color: #333

body
  font: 100% $font-stack
  color: $primary-color
```

However, when I do this, I just get the following error:

```
src/web-internal/server/applicaiton.py", line 8, in <module>
    sass.compile(dirname=('client/sass', 'client/css'), source_comments=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sass.py", line 516, in compile
    raise CompileError(v)
sass.CompileError: b"Error: top-level variable binding must be terminated by ';'\n        on line 2 of src/web-internal/server/../client/sass/test_sass.scss\n>> $primary-color: #333\n   ^\n"
```

I'd like to use SASS, and would perfer not to settle for SCSS. Does anyone have any suggestions? I feel like there is something in the [sass documentation](http://hongminhee.org/libsass-python/sass.html) that I am missunderstanding.

Comment: Can you show the folder structure of your app?

Comment: Your `sass`, `css` folders should be in the `static` named folder. See [here](http://hongminhee.org/libsass-python/frameworks/flask.html#id3) some info.

Comment: Thanks @doru but, do you think this is the problem even though my Flask app is started using `app = Flask(__name__,static_url_path="",static_folder=CLIENT_FOLDER)` where `CLIENT_FOLDER` is the `client` folder (`CLIENT_FOLDER=os.path.join(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),"..","client")`)

Comment: People are mostly going to be guessing unless you share a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @dirn, any suggestions what to remove, add, or verify in this example?

Comment: You provide an exception but no traceback. You reference a file containing a line of code but don't share the file. These are good places to start.

Comment: Thanks @dirn, I adjusted the question a little bit in response to your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I never got this working with `sass.compile` but I found a work around.

```
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start sassc with --watch
    sass_cmd = subprocess.Popen(['sass', '--watch', 'client/sass' + ':' + 'client/css'])
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python libsass package's `compile()` method supports the `indented` kwarg to tell the compiler if the given input is indented .sass or regular bracketed .scss.

If you are using indented .sass as your input, just use it like this:

```py
indented_sass_string = """

$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif
$primary-color: #333

body
  font: 100% $font-stack
  color: $primary-color
"""

css = sass.compile(string=indented_sass_string, indented=True)
```

I assume that this will work if you are passing entire directories. I am not sure what happens if you try to compile an entire directory which has a mix of .sass and .scss files.

See the docs: https://sass.github.io/libsass-python/sass.html#sass.compile

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile any file, then you can do it like this

```
import sass
sass.compile(dirname=("client/sass", "client/css"))
```

[libsass-python](https://sass.github.io/libsass-python/) documentation.